# Tell difference between functions that perform action and functions that return

Tags: python, function

Is there an easy way to determine/remember which functions return a new object and which act on the existing object.  For example, `list.append('new stuff')` acts on that actual object, whereas `string.rstrip()` returns a new string that needs to be assigned somewhere.

I'm forever having to look up (or open the Python Interpretor to check quickly) which functions act upon, and which functions return.

Comment: You need to check the manual to know for sure.

Comment: I think you just need to remember which things are mutable (lists, dicts, ...) and which are immutable (strings, tuples, ...).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Even mutable objects can be passed to functions which return new objects without mutating the passed one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's true, of course, but if you want to reason about whether a method will mutate an object or not, knowing whether or not it's mutable is a pretty good start.

Comment: Use a good IDE such as PyCharm which lets you quickly jump to the definition or show the documentation of a function with a simple mouse/key combination.

Comment: Lots of helpful info.  The immutable thing is so obvious I cant believe i didn't realize it sowhere along the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no completely reliable way, but there are a few good heuristics:

- If an object is immutable, none of its methods mutate it, of course, even the ones like `str.replace` that really sound mutative.
- Things like `sorted` or `set.intersection`, with adjective or noun names, generally produce a new object.
- If an object is mutable, methods with verb names generally modify the object. This would be stuff like `list.append` or `set.add`.

Unfortunately, not everyone picks good names, so we have things like [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html), which produces a sorted copy of a NumPy array and really should have been called `numpy.sorted`. The most reliable way will always be to check the docs or test it out in an interpreter session.

Answer (score 1):

That is what I normally do, I open the python interpreter and try different things by writing snippets. There are however more powerful ways to get metadata to display as you type, for example you could use PyCharm to give you [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html), which will tell you available functions within the object you are trying to access as well as arguments needed and return hints.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, no, there is not an easier way than those you describe.

The way most people (including me!) learn is to do more programming, remember the frequently used functions and check the manual on those you don't know :)